# technique of proving continuity complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

If I want to prove a function $f(t)$ is continuous at $ t_o$.  By def of continuity, I need to show that for $\epsilon >0 $, there exist $ \delta>0$ s.t 
$ |t-t_o| < \delta$ implies $ |f(t)-f(t_o)|< \epsilon $ .

If in order to show this, I need other condition to satisfy along with a bound on $ |t-t_o|$ to control $|f(t)-f(t_o)|$, then does it satisfy the def of continuity? since it seems that the only thing that we can control is $ |t-t_o|$ based on the definition of continuity.

For example, suppose $ h(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$ h(t) = \int_{\gamma_t} f(z) dz$$ where $\gamma_t $ is a family of closed curves for each $t \in [0,1] $ in $\mathbb{C}$.  If we want to show that $h(t)$ is continuous at $T$ in $[0,1]$, then we need to bound 
$$ |h(t)-h(T)| = \bigg| \int_{\gamma_t} f(z) dz - \int_{\gamma_T} f(z) dz \bigg|$$
By triangle inequality, this is less than or equal to 
$$ \bigg| \int_{\gamma_t} f(z) dz - \sum_{k=1}^n f(\gamma_t(t^*))(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) ) \bigg|$$ 
$$ + \bigg| \sum_{k=1}^n f(\gamma_t(t^*))(\gamma_t(p_k)-\gamma_t(p_{k-1}) ) - \int_{\gamma_T} f(z) dz \bigg|$$
where $ P = \{p_o, p_1,...,p_n\} $ is a partition of the interval of integration.

Now suppose that I can control the first term to be less than $\epsilon/2$ by increasing the partition $P$ and I can also bound the second term to be less than $\epsilon/2$ by controlling $ |t-T| $.
Then does this satisfy the def of continuous ? since I need to control not only $|t-T|$ but also the partition $P$ to achieve this???

sorry for the confusing question, thank you.